# rewrite http to https with ngnix behind load balancer

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

I'm using a Rackspace load balancer which enables me to set up my ssl key/pem inside of the admin panel. Everything works fine, I can use both http and https protocols. But if I try to redirect http to https using:

```
server{
  listen *:80;
  server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com; 
  rewrite ^ https://mydomain.com$request_uri? permanent;
```

...I get a redirect loop. I realize I'm not listening to port 443 but that's because the load balancer handled that for me. I also tried wrapping the rewrite in `if ($scheme ~* http){`to no avail.

The other part of my question is that I'd like to remove www from the url, can I do this with a single rewrite? Shouldn't the above rewrite take care of this as well?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The load balancer should be sending some indication to you of whether the connection was HTTPS. Ask Rackspace. (Oh, and you probably don't want to get rid of www...)

Comment: Interesting, I'll look into that. Why do you think I shouldn't get rid of www?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

sciurus is correct in that Rackspace's Cloud Load Balancers set the X-Forwarded-Proto to https when SSL is offloaded at the load balancer. In order to avoid a redirect loop in nginx, you should be able to add the following to the `location` section in the vhost configuration:

```
if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http") {
            rewrite  ^/(.*)$  https://mydomain.com/$1 permanent;
}
```

This should avoid the infinite redirect loop while redirecting non-https requests to https.

Answer (score 27):

By using nginx's built-in server variables `$request_uri` and `$server_name` you can do this without using regular expressions at all.  Add the following to your server's `location` block and you're done:

```
if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http") {
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

This assumes your load balancer is sending the `$http_x_forwarded_proto` header along with the request to your backend instance(s).  Other common headers include `$http_x_forwarded_scheme` and also just `$scheme`.

More information can be found in the nginx *Pitfalls and Common Mistakes* documentation : https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#taxing-rewrites

Comment: Should definitely use return over rewrite. Upvoted.

Comment: You can use `$host` instead of `$server_name`

Comment: does not work with server_name _; so one should use $host variable as @Yossi suggested.

Comment: I wonder can we use `$scheme` here?

Answer (score 1):

The load balancer always talks to you over http. What is happening is

1. The browser makes a request to port 80 on the load balancer
2. The load balancer makes a request to port 80 on your web server
3. Your web server sends a redirect to the user
4. The user makes a request to port 443 on the load balancer

Steps 2-4 keep repeating until the browser detect the redirect loop and gives up.

EDIT: To resolve this, only perform the rewrite when the X-Forwarded-Proto header is set to http. That header is how Rackspace's load balancer tells your web server the protocol via which it received the request.

Comment: I guess that would explain why $server_protocol always returns HTTP

Comment: So you answered why this is happening... any suggestions on how to fix?